# how to expose custom header on nginx

Tags: nginx, http-headers

Our https requests sending new header "X-XSRF-TOKEN" to the Nginx.
Some time the header coming "= null" to my backend servers.

MY question, is there any option to see this header in my access.log?

how can i make sure that the Nginx is not blocking the header.

I have to say 98% from the request, they are coming with correct value.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Of course, you can define any custom access log format and use any of the available nginx [internal variables](https://nginx.org/en/docs/varindex.html). The default nginx log format is:

```
log_format  combined  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
```

Just define a new access log format and add the [`$http_x_xsrf_token`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_http_) variable to it:

```
log_format  debug     '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" "$http_x_xsrf_token"';
access_log  /var/log/nginx/access_log  debug;
```